# iOS build machine setup: problem with certificates

Tags: ios

some background:

- work with multiple team mates
- each work on our own MBP
- I'm setting a build machine that we can `git push` to in order to generate a build (aim to allow anyone to push to the build machine and then generate an archive, upload to testflight and send on its way)

problem:

- getting my apple developer certificates on the build machine.

I installed Lion, XCode, etc and I signed into my developer account through Xcode organizer, provisioning profiles download,etc. but beside each one it says:

`valid signing identity not found`

I also download my certificate from the developer.apple.com page, imported it into keychain, etc but no luck.

Anyone else have a similar issue? Or maybe hints to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had to export private key as a p12 file.

This link http://forums.imore.com/ios-developer-forum/178890-developing-iphone-apps-multiple-machines-using-same-developer-certificate.html lead me to it.